# Django TemplateSyntaxError - 'staticfiles' is not a registered tag library

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-3.0

After upgrading to Django 3.0, I get the following `TemplateSyntaxError`:

```
In template /Users/alasdair//myproject/myapp/templates/index.html, error at line 1
'staticfiles' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of: admin_list admin_modify admin_urls cache i18n l10n log static tz
```

Here is my template

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<img src="{% static 'my_image.html' %}">
```

Answer (score 377, accepted):

If you have any of the following tags in your template:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}
{% load admin_static %}
```

Then replace it with:

```
{% load static %}
```

You have to make this change because `{% load staticfiles %}` and `{% load admin_static %}` were [deprecated in Django 2.1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/releases/2.1/#features-deprecated-in-2-1), and [removed in Django 3.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/3.0/#features-removed-in-3-0).

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work seamlessly with `Django==3.0.5`, `djangorestframework==3.11.0`, and `django_rest_swagger==2.2.0`. It would require a `collectstatic` followed by a replace.

Answer (score 20):

- Try `{% load static %}` instead of `{% load staticfiles %}`
- If effect of CSS or any other files doesn't reflect in your template then also write following lines in the end of your `settings.py` file

```py
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
VENV_PATH = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'static_root')
```

Comment: Adding STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')] solved the issue. Before I was adding static file directory to DIRS inside templates which didn't work. Many thanks!

Comment: This should be tagged as the correct answer. The other options are now obsoleted.

Comment: Does the CSS part work in windows 7 64bit also?
I tried the same but giving error

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me using django 3.1.4.

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style.css' %}">
```

its working for me

Answer (score 2):

this worked with me  replace `{% load static from staticfiles %}` with `{% load static %}`

**where :**

go to your virtual environment "venv" /lip/python3.X/site-packages/leaflet/templates/leaflet/admin/widget.html   and all of the  .**HTML** files in the directory

Comment: Changing files in `site-packages` is a bad idea. In your case, it would be better to upgrade [django-leaflet](https://pypi.org/project/django-leaflet/) to a newer version that supports Django 3.0+

Answer (score 0):

My issue was in step 4 from documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/

"4. Store your static files in a folder called static in your app. For example my_app/static/my_app/example.jpg."

Once I had corrected my directory structure to match everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem and attempted to resolve it using various methods. However, I eventually modified the next line of code where I referenced my CSS file. The solution is identical to the one mentioned above, but with an additional step.

```
   {% load staticfiles %}  
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}"/>
```

changed with :

```
   {% load static %}
<link href="{% static 'css/style.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: Changing the order of `rel` and `href` shouldn’t make any difference. Abayomi Olowu‘S answer was missing the `=` sign so I’ve added that in.