# TemplateSyntaxError at /en/admin/login/ 'staticfiles' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:

Tags: python, django-cms

I've installed django-cms. The first time I type `python manage.py runserver`, I get the error

```
'staticfiles' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_style_tags
admin_tree
admin_tree_list
admin_urls
cache
cms_admin
cms_alias_tags
cms_js_tags
cms_static
cms_tags
djangocms_text_ckeditor_tags
easy_thumbnails_tags
filer_admin_tags
filer_image_tags
filer_tags
i18n
l10n
log
menu_tags
sekizai_tags
snippet_tags
static
thumbnail
tz
```

All the solutions basically say the same thing: Use `{% load static %}` instead of `{% load staticfiles %}`

I changed the files where these errors occurred....and it worked! I get the django CMS page saying that installation was successful.

But now it also says that "the form could not be loaded. Please check that the server is running correctly." This message displays after I log in with "admin" as username and password (which somehow was created for me) on the localhost. And yes, the server is running correctly. No issues

Could it be that the edits I did changed some of the files? I only changed the static files as I was supposed to in the solutions on this site.

Comment: Actually I just started a new project and showed the same error, seems to be an error with the new version 3.7.2, I'm opening a new issue now.

Answer (score 0):

That's due to deprecations, as mentioned in [Django TemplateSyntaxError - 'staticfiles' is not a registered tag library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55929472/django-templatesyntaxerror-staticfiles-is-not-a-registered-tag-library)

It's already logged as an issue against django-cms here https://github.com/divio/django-cms/issues/6844

In the meantime

```
pipenv install 'django<2.1'
```

(or pip, if that's your pref) will get you going.