# 'staticfiles' is not a registered tag library: These solutions don't work

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm new to Heroku and Django.
Now I'm in the middle of [Getting Started on Heroku with Python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#provision-a-database).
When I access `https://(...secret...)-app-123.herokuapp.com/db`,
I got the following error:

```
'staticfiles' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
static
tz
```

Then I found [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55929472/django-templatesyntaxerror-staticfiles-is-not-a-registered-tag-library).
However, these solutions don't solve my problem.

Firstly, I changed

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

to

```
{% load static %}
```

... in `db.html`.

It gave me:

```
run python manage.py migrate
Running python manage.py migrate on ⬢ (...secret...)-app-123... up, run.3361 (Free)
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, hello, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
  Your models have changes that are not yet reflected in a migration, and so won't be applied.
  Run 'manage.py makemigrations' to make new migrations, and then re-run 'manage.py migrate' to apply them.
```

Since the error message tells me to run `manage.py makemigrations`, I ran:

```
manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxxxx\python-getting-started\manage.py", line 8, in ?
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

No module?
Django is installed on my machine.
I didn't know what to do, so I updated Django on my local machine:

```
C:\Users\xxxxx\python-getting-started>pip install django --upgrade
Requirement already up-to-date: django in c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (3.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: sqlparse>=0.2.2 in c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from django) (0.4.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: pytz in c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from django) (2020.1)
Requirement already satisfied, skipping upgrade: asgiref~=3.2.10 in c:\users\xxxxx\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.8_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python38\site-packages (from django) (3.2.10)
```

... But, it doesn't solve my problem.

I also added:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
VENV_PATH = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(VENV_PATH, 'static_root')
```

at the end of `settings.py`, but it doesn't work, too.

What else can I do?

For your info, there hasn't been any error until now at [Getting Started on Heroku with Python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#provision-a-database).
You can't even reach here, if you have any error.

Please freely ask me about my settings, type this, type that, etc.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use virtual environment. It will be easier to manage your django project inside virtual environment.

Comment: Thank you. I've just created a virtual environment called `djenv`, following the instruction [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/set-up-virtual-environment-for-python-using-anaconda/). The result is like this: (djenv) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\djenv:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
alabaster                 0.7.12                   py37_0
   :
django                    2.2.5                    py37_1 ... What to do now? `manage.py makemigrations` still give me the error.

Comment: When I started the Heroku-Django instruction, I was using `base` environment. Do I have to do the whole process again from scratch?